# Isolating variabel in formula

Tags: computer-science

I am doing some cryptography programming, and I have to isolate `a` in the following formula in order to decode some cipher-messages. $${g^a\mod p}=21$$

I am pretty far from implementing the isolation, but I would like to understand how it is done. So if you have a solution, I would appreciate pointers to some material to look into

***Edit***

---

It should be noted that `p` is a prime and `g` is a primitive root modulo of `p`

I expect the solution to be done with trial and error, since I am trying to make a brute-force program to find `a`. p will be a prime between 7 and 23

Comment: Refer to discrete logarithm. wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm  algorithm : https://cp-algorithms.com/algebra/discrete-log.html

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts on this site.

Comment: @saulspatz thanks for the tip!

Comment: Since $g$ is a primitive root we know there exists a unique number $a \in \{1,2, \dots, p-1 \}$ such that $g^a \equiv 21 \pmod p$. the set of all solutions will be $a+ k(p-1)$ where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ since $g$ is a primitive root and $g^{a+k(p-1)} \equiv g^a(g^{p-1})^k \equiv g^a(1)^k \equiv g^a \pmod p$ (using fermat's little theorem). So one option is to check iteratively among the $p-1$ options

Comment: @Aladin Would you agree to making a chat? I have some questions, you don't have to tag along until everything clicks

Comment: Ok. by the way my answer is correct only if $\gcd(p,21) = 1$. otherwise, there is no solution